# How to uninstall/re-install a clickonce app

Tags: clickonce

I have about a dozen clickonce applications sitting on a server that needs to be decommissioned.  Most of these apps were published with an installation mode of "available offline as well". I'd like to have the application automatically uninstall itself next time it's run and then re-install itself from the new server where these apps will be published.

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished?

Tks

Comment: Are you able to put a redirect in your DNS so that the current update URL stays valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. It's explained in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx) about renewing certificates. You can ignore all the stuff about certs and concentrate on the bit about uninstalling/reinstalling programmatically. The code is actually available from [here](https://nightbird.blob.core.windows.net/robindotnet/ClickOnce_ExpiringCerts.zip). Good luck.